# How can I pass textbox value from usercontrol(ascx) to another page (aspx) using Server.Transfer()

Tags: c#, server.transfer, kentico

I am writing one user control (webpart) in kentico. I want to pass textboxes' value from usercontrol to aspx page using Server.Transfer().

Can it be? If so, how can I do like that?

Best Regards,

Reds

Comment: That's not what Server.Transfer is for - just use AJAX to send data to the server without reloading the page or submitting a form.

Comment: Why do you not store the value in session?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Alberto Leon. Now I solve my problem with using session like you suggested. :) I still want to know how can I get value from page(aspx) after I used Server.Transfer(pageurl,true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't particularly like this method, I prefer to use Sessions to pass data between pages, but if you need to do this here how it's done according to the this [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219294).

Here's TL;DR summary. It requires three scripts/pages:

**Form.ascx** - this will be the control that contains the text box value.

**FormParsingScript.aspx** (referenced in the Form.ascx in the Action attribute) - this will perform the actual `Server.Transfer "FinalScript.aspx"`  call

**FinalScript.aspx** which will display the contents of `Response.Form["TextBoxName"]` (HTTP POST) or `Response.QueryString["TextBoxName"]` (HTTP GET)

Comment: can you show me example? I don't understand what you wanna mean.

Comment: Thanks! I have already tested. It's work. Thanks you very much. For my solution, I use session objects because my user control is just logic to redirect based on what the client type (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]) and Cookie value. So I don't have form object. Thanks for your response to Server.Transfer() Mehtod.